# How can I move a nav menu to the right side of the page?

Tags: html, css

[image: I want to do this]

I tried adding `float: right` and `margin-right: 0` to `.links` but it didn't work.

Here I have a div with class `.links`. How do I make it render on the right side.

```css
.navbar {
  padding: 5px;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.ls,
.rs {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.links {
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px;
}

.links ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.links ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="ls">
      <a href=""><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" height="40px"></a>
      <a href="">Name</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="rs">
      <a href="">Menu</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <nav class="links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Content</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Content</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Content</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Content</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Note that floats are not a modern layout strategy. They were (mis)used for alignment years ago because nothing better existed, but now it does. Use flexbox for all of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would also try flexbox.
Under this link, you can find everything you need to know on how they work, it is a really useful tutorial:

[A guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Hi, this helped me but I cannot figure out why when I added by code to `.links` it didn't worked but when I added it to `nav .links` it worked.

Comment: Do you know why it happened?

Comment: @DisplayName I am not entirely sure of this, but I suppose it is because of the CSS targeting scopes, meaning you have to reference the element correctly in the CSS file. I would also have thought that it should work with just `.links` (if you do not have this class elsewhere);

But I would use id's though instead of classes, if you do not plan to target multiple elements with the same styling.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the property `right: 0` on the `.links` class to move it to the far right.

Here is some really useful [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/right) on how the `right` property behaves in a number of scenarios.

```css
.navbar {
  padding: 5px;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.ls, .rs{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.links {
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

.links ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.links ul li a{
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="ls">
      <a href=""><img src="logo.svg" height="40px"></a>
      <a href="">Name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rs">
      <a href="">Menu</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Content</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Content</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Content</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Content</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have `width: 100%` for your `.links` and `float: right` for `.links ul`.

```css
.navbar {
  padding: 5px;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.ls,
.rs {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.links {
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.links ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
}

.links ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="ls">
      <a href=""><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" height="40px"></a>
      <a href="">Name</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="rs">
      <a href="">Menu</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <nav class="links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Content</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Content</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Content</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Content</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```